# How do I get a perticular subcategory that has the same name under the other category in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a shop-application and theres `categories` and `subcategories`, I have 3 categories and under each one of those there's a subcategory called `Other` and when I click on the `url` for it I get this error:

`MultipleObjectsReturned at /categories/subcategory/Other, get() returned more than one SubCategory -- it returned 3!`

I do realise that using `filter` is not an option since it would return 3 values and a url can't accept a queryset as an argument, could I perhaps somehow also use the subcategorys category `title` to filter the query or do you have any other ideas?

Here is the code:

**urls.py**

```
path('subcategory/<str:title>/', views.subcategory, name='subcategory'),
```

**views.py**

```
def subcategory(request, title):
    subcategory = SubCategory.objects.get(title=title)
    products = Product.objects.filter(subcategory=subcategory)
    return render(request, 'subcategory.html', {'subcategory': subcategory,
                                                'products': products})
```

Here are my models:

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)



class SubCategory(models.Model):    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False, blank=False)

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, 
                                 related_name='subcategories', 
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Please show your models.py

Comment: You can get rid of error by writing `SubCategory.objects.filter(title=title).last()`. But I don't think that is what you want. Why you are using non-unique field in url as identifier? (Including your models in question will contribute to more clear answers).

Comment: ok I will include my models in a sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the `products` with:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(subcategory__title=title)
```

so you can retrieve the queryset of `SubCategory`s (can be multiple) and `Product`s with:

```
def subcategory(request, title):
    subcategory = SubCategory.objects.filter(title=title)
    products = Product.objects.filter(subcategory__title=title)
    return render(
        request,
        'subcategory.html',
        {'subcategory': subcategory, 'products': products}
    )
```

Comment: It have me `The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing`, also I am using a sort-of url-path thingy in my template and it is using the `subcategory` as a `url` argument so queryset really isn't an option here

Comment: @SLDem: yes, I made a typo: it is `s/=subcategory/=title/`.

Comment: Can you explain this part `s/=subcategory/=title/` a little better please?

Comment: nvm, I see it, will try

Comment: now it shows me all the products for all the subcategories and the url thing isnt working because I'm passing a queryset

Comment: @SLDem: exactly what is `title`? With the given modification, you retrieve all `Product`s with a `subcategory` with the given title...

Comment: `title` is just a title for the subcategory, I just have 3 `subcategories` with the same `title` under 3 `categories` called `Other` and I when I click on the link to subcategory it returns the error becase `get` returns 3 same `title` values, and I do need to have the exact `subcategory` passed in the context due to the url-path I'm building on top of my page :)

Comment: @SLDem: well that is not possible with `title`, since there is no distinction between two sub categories with the same name. You can for example add the "category" (parent) as well to make filtering more precise, or use the primary key of the subcategory.

Comment: thats what I was thinking I would do but thought that maybe theres a different solution, anyways, using cateogry in the path is quite common practice so I'll do that, thanks :)